# Getting a file directory tag {filedir_1} out of a query module result

Tags: assets, query

I'm using a query module to get the results of a channel entry. I've retrieved the correct url:
 {filedir_1}/newimages/img1.png

but it does not replace the {filedir_1} with the necessary prefix like it normally does. Will the query module parse tags from its results?

this field happens to be an assets field but i would think it would parse like a regular image url would.

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

All results of queries created by the `exp:channel:entries` module are parsed by the function parse_images on $this->EE->typography.

When you use the `exp:query` module, you need to do this by your own; but, luckily, Rob Sanchez coded an [addon](https://github.com/rsanchez/parse_file_paths) for this.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT field_id_1 AS file FROM exp_channel_data" parse="inward"}
  {exp:parse_file_paths}
    {file}
  {/exp:parse_file_paths}
{/exp:query}
```